# JDBC in Google Script "&amp;" to "&"

Tags: javascript, mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-apps

When getting the values from MySql database in Google Spreadsheets using JDBC service and I get the ampersand character as `&amp;` instead of `&`. I would like to know how should I make the call so I directly get `&` as value.

I am using the following connection: `"jdbc:mysql://ip:port/server?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"`. Also, I am using `rs.getString()` method to take the data from the query.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are outputting your data, but this is usually a cause:

> In HTML, the ampersand character (“&”) declares the beginning of an
>   entity reference (a special character). If you want one to appear in
>   text on a web page you should use the encoded named entity “&”
>   This seems like a simple rule, but what about urls in HTML, javascript files, javascript in HTML, etc… Here’s a little guide to help clear up that ampersand HTML confusion:

**Text in HTML:**

```
<p>Jack &amp; Jill ran up the hill.</p>
A link in HTML (or any HTML attribute value):

<a href="http://google.com/?l=1&amp;q=rick+roll">tired meme</a>
```

**A link in javascript:**

```
window.location = 'http://google.com/?l=1&q=rick+roll';
```

If you’re using a web framework that escapes variables for you and you pass in a url as a variable into javascript, then you’ll have to make sure it doesn’t encode the ampersands. In Django, you would write something like this: `window.location = '{{ url|escapejs }}';`

Also, if this is inline javascript—in an HTML document, not a separate .js file—then you still shouldn’t escape the ampersand, which means the document will not validate as XHTML. Either throw it into a separate .js file or stop worrying so much about validating your code.

**Inside an onclick in HTML:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='?l=1&amp;q=rick+roll';return false">
    kablammo!
</a>
```

This is redundant to the second example, but worth pointing out since it’s javascript inside an attribute of an HTML tag.

**Dynamically in Javascript (example using jQuery):**

```
$('#result').text('Jack & Jill'); // .text() escapes the text for you
$('#result').html('Jack &amp; Jill'); // .html() sets the HTML directly
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Jack &amp; Jill';
```

Reference information: [Click Here](http://mrcoles.com/blog/how-use-amersands-html-encode/)